# Calling Form.Refresh or Reload from static method c#

Tags: c#

I have a static method that  gets some data from Web Service ("GET"), if i gets HttpWebResponse with some status code (403,401), i have to reset, refresh or reload the Form1_load. Since my method is static, i cannot make instance of Form1. Is there solution for this ?

Comment: You'll have to find a way to get the reference to your Form1 over to the static method via a parameter or another static global.  You can also make use of [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Application_OpenForms)

Comment: What triggers the static method call? Is it done from this form? Is it part of the application startup? Something else? At the point it time it is called do you have an instance of this form available? Supply some code to make your question more concrete.

Comment: You can make Form1 as a singleton or add a static method to allow any instance of Form1 to register to static part of the class, using one sttaic reference (same as using a singleton) or a list, hence static code will be able to access instance members.

Comment: I got this message when i used Application.OpenForms - Cross-thread operation not valid: Control "Form1" accessed from a thread otherthan the thread it was created on.

Comment: Once you have a reference to Form1, via Application.OpenForms, use `Invoke()` to run what you want on the UI thread.  Do a quick search, you'll come up w/ tons of examples...

Comment: Thank you all ... Problem solved...